# NetSuite: simultaneous browser session between sandbox, production and debugger domain

Tags: netsuite

My mates and me have issues with be logged in simultaneously in the different domains of NetSuite, especially when using the debugger.

After logging in into the debugger.sandbox domain I switch back to the sandbox and then back to the debugger and I got this message.

> Someone has logged in as this user from a different computer or browser window. Only one person may login as a given user at a time. As a consequence, this session has been terminated.
>   To have multiple windows logged in as the same user, use File->New->Window from your browser's menu bar.

Seriously?
Why it should matter if I use another tab or another window?

Comment: I can't answer why it matters, but I also felt that switching back and forth between system.sandbox and debugger.sandbox was too disruptive to my workflow.  Now I always use the debugger.sandbox domain for all of my dev work just in case I need to use the debugger.  I just need to remember to change the host name if I ever copy/past a sandbox URL to another user.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite uses browser sessions to manage logins based on the domain, and you cannot be logged in to two accounts on the same domain at once. You could, for instance, be logged in to a Production and a Sandbox account in the same browser at the same time because they are different domains, but *not* two Production accounts at once. Since internally the debugger is actually the same domain as sandbox, you cannot be logged in to both at once.

You *may* be able to work around this issue by using two separate **browsers**, one for the sandbox and one for the debugger, but I have a feeling it will still kick you out because it will technically see them as the same account.